Error with Spice Model of MOSFET STL3N65M2 in LTspice
When simulating a very simple H-bridge in LTspice based on STL3N65M2 the following error arises:

Singular matrix:  Check nodes e:m1:1#branch and m4:alfaa Iteration No. 6
Fatal Error: Singular matrix:  check nodes e:m1:1#branch and m4:alfaa Iteration No. 6

I attached an exemplary circuit and the simulation model of the MOSFET provided by ST. Any idea where the problem is or how it can be fixed?

*****************************************************************
******STMicroelectronics MOSFET, IGBT and Bipolar Library *******
*****************************************************************
*                                                               *
* Models provided by STMicroelectronics are not guaranteed to   *
* fully represent all the specifications and operating          *
* characteristics of the product behavior that they reproduce.  *
* The model describes the characteristics of a typical device.  *
* In all cases, the current product data sheet contains all     *
* information to be used like final design guidelines and the   *
* only actual performance specification.                        *
* Altough models can be a useful tool in evaluating device      *
* performance, they cannot model exact device performance under *
* all conditions.                                               *
* STMicroelectronics therefore does not assume any              *
* responsibility arising from their use.                        *
* STMicroelectronics reserves the right to change models        *
* without prior notice.                                         *
*                                                               *
* Note: The model doesn't take into account the drain, gate,    *
* source inductances.If these contributions have to be          *
* considered it is possible include the inductors externally.   *
* For this package the values can be estimated as follow        *
*                                                               *
* Ldrain= 1nH ,Lsource=2nH and Lgate=2.5nH                      *
*****************************************************************

.SUBCKT STL3N65M2_V2 drain gate source 
*****************************************************************
E1  Tj  Val_T   VALUE={TEMP}
R1  Val_T   0   1E-03
*****************************************************************
Rtk  Tj 0 1E010
Rtk1 Tj 0 1E010
*****************************************************************
VLd drain d1k 0
V_Read d1k d1 0
VLs source ss 0
VLg gate g2 0
Rg1 g2 g {Rg}
.PARAM  Rg=8.5
*****************************************************************
.PARAM AreaCap={1} Area={1} Gfs={1}
*****************************************************************
.PARAM  Vth0=3.82 KpSat0=10 KpLin0=10   
.PARAM  Rs=24E-02 Drs=-1.5 
.PARAM  Vthx=3.5E-03 KSat=-0.6 KLin=-0.5    
.PARAM  Lambda=0.001 Rdrain={1.37/Area}  
.PARAM  Rx=8.9 Rpa=1E-06 Unt=-3.15
*****************************************************************
.FUNC Vth1(x) {Vth0-Vthx*(x-27)}
.FUNC kpsat(x) {KpSat0*((x+273)/300)**(KSat)}
.FUNC kplin(x) {KpLin0*((x+273)/300)**(KLin)}
*****************************************************************
V2xx  d1 22xxx 0
E2xxx 22xxx d VALUE={R2(I(V2xx),V(TJ))}
.FUNC R2(I1,T2) {I1*(Rdrain+Rpa*I1**Rx)/((((T2+273)/300)**(Unt))*Area)}
*****************************************************************
R_Grs ss s 1E03
V1xx 11xxx ss 0
E1xxx 11xxx s VALUE={R1(Limit(I(V1xx),-1MEG,1MEG),V(TJ))}
.FUNC R1(I1,T1) {-(I1)*((Rs/(Area*(((T1+273)/300)**(Drs)))))}
*****************************************************************
Gmos d s VALUE {0.9*Gfs*(IF(V(d,s)>0,(IF(V(g,s)<Vth1(V(TJ)),0,
+(IF((V(d,s)<(V(g,s)-Vth1(V(TJ)))*kpsat(V(TJ))/kplin(V(TJ))),(1+Lambda*V(d,s))*kplin(V(TJ))/2*V(d,s)*
+(2*(V(g,s)-Vth1(V(TJ)))-kplin(V(TJ))/kpsat(V(TJ))*V(d,s)),
+(1+Lambda*V(d,s))*kpsat(V(TJ))/2*(V(g,s)-Vth1(V(TJ)))**2)))),-(IF(V(g,s)<Vth1(V(TJ)),0,
+(IF((V(s,d)<(V(g,s)-Vth1(V(TJ)))*kpsat(V(TJ))/kplin(V(TJ))),(1+Lambda*V(s,d))*kplin(V(TJ))/2*V(s,d)*
+(2*(V(g,s)-Vth1(V(TJ)))-kplin(V(TJ))/kpsat(V(TJ))*V(s,d)),
+(1+Lambda*V(s,d))*kpsat(V(TJ))/2*(V(g,s)-Vth1(V(TJ)))**2))))))} 
*****************************************************************
CGS source g {155E-12*AreaCap}
RCGS source g 1000E06 
*****************************************************************
EDeV DeV1 0 VALUE {V(d,g)}
C_DeV1 DeV1 DeV2 1E-12
R_DeV DeV2 DeV3 1E-06
V_Miller DeV3 0 0 
G_Miller d g VALUE ={AreaCap*1*V(alfa)*i(V_Miller)*1E12}
*****************************************************************
RCap Alfa 0 1E03
ECap Alfa 0 TABLE ={V(d,g)}
+(-0.1,285.03p) 
+(0.1,110.03p) 
+(0.2,107.2p) 
+(0.5,98.85p) 
+(1,85.45p) 
+(2,67.24p) 
+(3,55.48p) 
+(5,41.2p) 
+(7,31.87p) 
+(10,21.65p) 
+(17,3.56p) 
+(20,2.18p) 
+(25,1.55p) 
+(30,1.06p) 
+(43,0.51p) 
+(70,0.26p) 
+(100,0.19p) 
+(150,0.16p) 
+(200,0.16p) 
+(250,0.16p) 
+(300,0.16p) 
+(350,0.16p) 
+(400,0.16p) 
+(450,0.16p) 
+(500,0.16p) 
+(550,0.16p) 
+(600,0.16p) 
+(650,0.16p) 
*****************************************************************
EDeVc DeV1c 0 VALUE {V(d,s)}
C_DeV1c DeV1c DeV2c 1E-12
R_DeVc DeV2c DeV3c 1E-06
V_Millerc DeV3c 0 0 
G_Coss d s VALUE ={1*AreaCap*V(Alfa2)*i(V_Millerc)*1E12}
*****************************************************************
RCap2 Alfa2 0 1E03
ECap2 Alfa2 0 TABLE ={V(d,s)}
+(0.1,1320.36p) 
+(0.2,1235.09p) 
+(0.5,1078.17p) 
+(1,925.35p) 
+(2,760.25p) 
+(3,662.06p) 
+(5,551.29p) 
+(7,484.9p) 
+(10,419.67p) 
+(17,340.85p) 
+(20,243.93p) 
+(25,79.11p) 
+(30,50.63p) 
+(43,26.71p) 
+(70,10.79p) 
+(100,7.84p) 
+(150,7.16p) 
+(200,6.82p) 
+(250,6.49p) 
+(300,6.2p) 
+(350,5.84p) 
+(400,5.6p) 
+(450,5.39p) 
+(500,5.13p) 
+(550,4.81p) 
+(600,4.61p) 
+(650,4.55p) 
*****************************************************************
V_Sense2  sx s  0
*****************************************************************
.PARAM RAV=1.6 BVDSS=1
G_BVdss d1bVdss1 ss VALUE={I_BVdss(V(d1bVdss1,ss),V(Tj))}
R_GBdss d1bVdss1 0 1E12
.FUNC I_BVdss(z,k1) {(exp(min(-175+z/(bvd(k1)),7))-0E-12)}
.FUNC bvd(k) {3.95*BVDSS+0.0031*k}
R_BVdss d1 d1bVdss1 {RAV}
*****************************************************************
.PARAM ResDiodo={0.003/AreaCap}
V_Diodo d1zd d1z 0
G_Diode source d1zd VALUE={I_Diode(V(source,d1zd),V(Tj))}
R_X source d1zd 1E12
.FUNC I_Diode(z3,k3) {(exp(min(-15+z3/(did(k3)),7))-0E-12)}
.FUNC did(k4) {0.049-65E-06*k4}
R_G_R_didd d1 d1z {ResDiodo}
*****************************************************************
E_E001 ba 0 VALUE {-I(V_Diodo)}
R_R002 aa ba 5E03
C aa 0 17E-12
.PARAM Irrm=17E05
*****************************************************************
R_edep drain d_dedep 30
E_Eds d_dedep edep VALUE {-V(aa,0)*Irrm*AreaCap}
Edeva dev1a 0 value {v(edep,source)}
C_dev1a dev1a dev2a 1E-12
R_deva dev2a dev3a 1E-06
V_millera dev3a 0 0 
G_millera edep source  value ={v(alfaa)*i(V_millera)*1E12}
*****************************************************************
Rcapa alfaa 0 1E03
Ecapa alfaa 0 TABLE ={V(Tj)}
+(25,1p)
+(150,0.85p)  
*****************************************************************
.ENDS STL3N65M2_V2


Crude workaround, but what happens if you open that text file in LTspice, right click on the STL... after .subckt and automatically generate a symbol from it?

A symbol is generated without any errors. However, if I use that symbol in my simulation I get the same error as described above.

Seems like a buggy model that fails to converge. Have you tried to contact ST and report this issue?

In fact, I hadn't even considered contacting ST about it. I'll do that next time. I can work with the solution below from Ste Kulov for now.

Like others have already mentioned, your issues seem to be due to a poorly constructed model which causes the value of the current through R1 to diverge to 1.#QNAN (not a number) amps.  After playing around with some of the subcircuit, it seems it would take a lot of time to try and locate the problem and fix it.  This is probably better suited for ST themselves, specifically the individual there that constructed the model.  You can try asking them directly if they can do this.
In the meantime, I think a better use of your time would be to construct your own VDMOS model from the datasheet.  There is a tool on the LTspice Groups.io which can help you do this.  Note: You need to make an account before you can access the files for this group.
https://groups.io/g/LTspice/files/z_groups.io/Util/setup-VDmosToolV8.zip
https://groups.io/g/LTspice/files/z_yahoo/Util/Model%20Tools/Board%20Level%20MOSFET%20%28VDmos%29/Software/HelpPages%20Mostool.pdf
I just tried it for the first time myself on your STL3N65M2, and it wasn't that hard to do when following the HelpPages Mostool.pdf document.  Here is what my setup and output look like.



.MODEL STL3N65M2 VDMOS(KP=0.833 RS=0.016 RD=1.4188 RG=8.5 VTO=3.0 
+LAMBDA=0.03 CGDMAX=180p CGDMIN=0p CGS=155p TT=265n a=11.84
+IS=2.06E-03 N=5.575 RB=0.000001 BV=650 IBV=1u m=0.679 Vj=0.1 Cjo=1890.0pF)

Using this VDMOS model in your circuit seems to resolve the divergence issue.  I had to add the startup flag to the .tran statement because LTspice has trouble finding the operating point for this circuit.

Please also pay attention to the important point in qrk's answer about shoot-through.

Cool hint about the VDMOS model generation tool of Hendrik Zwerver. Thanks!

I agree with Ken Grimes. Thanks for explaining this handy tool for creating your own VDMOS models! Of course, I am aware of the shoot-through. My circuit was merely a highly simplified example to illustrate the problem with the MOSFET model.

LTspice doesn't like the transistor model, even when using different integration methods. The model may have syntax that doesn't work right with LTspice. If you set the B+ voltage to < 20 V the simulation will run. Set it to 50 V and the simulation crashes. I tried a random MOSFET from the LTspice selection list (BSC16DN25NS3) and the simulation runs fine.
Beware of shoot-through. The PWM sources as defined will probably turn on the top and bottom transistors simultaneously during the transitions. I used the following definitions:
PWM1: PULSE(0 12 0 10n 10n 0.5m 1m)
PWM2: PULSE(0 12 0.505m 10n 10n 0.49m 1m)
